# pointer to pointer dynamic array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've been having bad luck with dynamic pointers when I want to close it. why the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer? how can I close my array?

```
int main()
{
    .
    .   
    int **W;
    W = new int* [n];
    for (int i=1; i <= n; i++)
        W[i] = new int[n];
    .
    .
    .
    ast(n,W);

    for(int i = 1; i <=n ; i++)
    {
        delete W[i];
    }
    delete W;
    getch();
}
void ast (int n,int **W)
{
    int **D;
    D = new int* [n];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        D[i] = new int[n];

    D=W;
    for (int k=1;k<=n;k++)
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
                D[i][j]=min(D[i][j],D[i][k]+D[k][j]);
    .
    .
    for(int i = 1; i <=n ; i++)
    {
        delete D[i];
    }
    delete D;
}
```

Comment: W indices are from 0 to n-1 instead of 1 to n.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: You should loop from 0 to n-1 instead of 1 to n. Better still, use std::vector.

Comment: I start array index with 0 to <n but it already is false!

Comment: @illusionist_yahya You're working with "dynamic arrays" and you were not aware that (even simple) arrays start at index 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid range of indices of an array with `N` elements is `[0, N-1]`.
Thus instead of for example this loop

```
for (int i=1; i <= n; i++)
         ^^^^ ^^^^^^
```

you have to write

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
```

As you used operator `new []` you have to use operator `delete []`
So instead of

```
for(int i = 1; i <=n ; i++)
{
    delete W[i];
}
```

and

```
delete W;
```

you have to write

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    delete [] W[i];
}
```

and

```
delete []W;
```

Function `ast` does not make sense because apart from other errors it has a memory leak. At first you allocate memory and assign its address to pointer `D` and then you overwrite this value of the pointer

```
void ast (int n,int **W)
{
    int **D;
    D = new int* [n];
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        D[i] = new int[n];

    D=W; // <== ???
```